# How to print in decimal instead of hex using printf with esp-idf

Tags: esp-idf

I am trying to print CAN bus messages that are received by an ESP32-S3 using the esp-idf framework. The provided example code for TWAI/CAN bus from the framework is shown below:

```c
printf("ID is %d\n", message.identifier);
if (!(message.rtr)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < message.data_length_code; i++) {
        printf("Data byte %d = %d\n", i, message.data[i]);
    }
}
```

If I send a CAN message with ID 123, it displays as 291, which is the same value but in hex. How can I specify the output format of the printf function?

I have googled and tried many solutions but I cannot seem to print the values in decimal.

[Here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/api-reference/peripherals/twai.html) is a link to the TWAI API reference for esp-idf

I have tried the following:

```c
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n",a);
    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)a
```

But none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

val = 291 decimal:

printf("%d", val);

Outputs --> 291

printf("0x%x", val);

Outputs --> 0x123

The %x formatting variable tells printf to display the value as Hexadecimal. You can also specify the number of digits to display.

printf("0x%04x", val);

Outputs --> 0x0123